# How do I create a method that throws the 'UnsupportedOperationException' if methods color and size are called

Tags: java, exception

I am trying to create a method that throws the 'UnsupportedOperationException' if the methods color and size are called

Comment: What's the question here?  You just throw an UnsupportedOperationException like any other exception.

Comment: Please edit the question to include your code, and explain exactly where you are stuck.